# Windows10 no longer stays asleep after configuring sshd

Tags: windows-10, sleep, openssh, sshd

I've had Windows 10 Home Edition running for a year and half without problems. I set up my PC's power button to put the OS into sleep mode. The other day I was trying to set up sshd. I used Windows PoweShell to run some commands [like in this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse).

Ever since then, Windows no longer stays asleep. I press the power button and Windows goes through the motions of going into sleep mode. It hums for a bit then the screen goes blank. But then after a few minutes, the screen turns back on and the log in screen is shown.

Similar behavior happens when I enable Wi-Fi Mobile Hotspot, allowing me to tether my cell phone to my PC's internet connection. When I have Mobile Hotspot enabled, the computer refuses to enter sleep mode.

I tried undo my sshd installation, but these commands didn't resolve the issue:

```
# Uninstall the OpenSSH Client
Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0

# Uninstall the OpenSSH Server
Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

So I'm at a loss of what to try next.

Comment: There is a command, which escapes me, which will indicate what exactly is preventing a machine from going into a specific power state.  Have you used that command?  (There are hundreds of articles on how to determine what prevents machines from going to sleep).

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you so much. I used [(this tutorial)](https://windowsreport.com/windows-8-windows-10-wakes-sleep-fix/) to resolve the issue. Particularly the `powercfg -lastwake` command.